# Would like to add the `data` parameter only when it has value if not then don't add data in the parameter string in the JQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to add the `data` parameter only when it has value if not then don't add data in the parameter string.

Currently, it is throwing unexpected token `if` and data values shows `undefined`

```
function Data() {
  if ($("#data").val().length != 0) {
    "&data=" + $("#data").val();
  }
}

function check() {
  launch += & firstname = " + $("#
  first ").val() + " & data = " + Data();           
}
```

Adding the parameter in this way

```
"&data=" + Data();
```

Comment: `launch += & firstname = " + $("#` is invalid syntax. It looks like you're missing some quotes.

Comment: `Data()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: I think there must be a problem with the way you copied `check()`. Nothing in it makes sense.

Comment: If you're building an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` string, jQuery has the handy [$.param()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) method for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return an empty string if there's no data value.

You need to fix the quoting in `check()`. And it doesn't need `&data=`, because that's added by `Data()`.

You should call `encodeURIComponent()` to ensure that the values are properly encoded.

If you're using `$.ajax()`, you can avoid all of this by putting the parameters in an object instead of a string. Then you can just conditionally add the `data:` property to the object.

```js
function Data() {
  if ($("#data").val()) {
    return "&data=" + encodeURIComponent($("#data").val());
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}

function check() {
  launch += "&firstname=" + encodeURIComponent($("#first ").val()) + Data();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Looks like you're trying to build a URL-encoded string.

I strongly suggest building up an object of parameters and passing that through [URLSearchParams()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) or jQuery's [$.param()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/). That way it will be properly encoded

```js
const params = {
  firstname: $("#first").val(),
};
const data = $("#data").val();
if (data) {
  params.data = data;
}

const launch = (new URLSearchParams(params)).toString();
// or = $.param(params)

console.log("launch:", launch)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input readonly id="first" value="Boaty McBoatFace">
<input readonly id="data" value="" placeholder="data">
```